# query_posts: how to show all 'meta_value' containing a specific word?

Tags: wp-query

How could you display all the post in a loop with a (custom) meta_value containing a word/phrase? for exemple get al the post where meta contains 'test'.

```
query_posts('post_type=SOME&category_name_2=SOME&meta_value= 'Cotains the word 'test' ??? ');
```

so when the meta tags are 'test movie' or just 'test' you get them both.?

Answer (score 2):

No need for a custom query. Since 3.1, you can use a 'meta query';

```
query_posts( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 
            'key' => 'meta_key_name',
            'value' => 'test',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
) );
```

Check out [the codex on custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: You lack one more array level in `meta_query` and `%` are added automatically when using `LIKE` compare.

Answer (score 1):

by Using "Custom select query"

```
<?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value LIKE '%test%' 
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'  
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```