# How to force Media manager to overwrite files of same name?

Tags: theme-development, media-library, uploads

I have a widget that works with my theme that expects images named in a certain way, slide1.png, slide2.png, etc...

However, when the user uploads their own images, named slide1.png, slide2.png, etc to the media library, rather than updating the images with the new ones, WordPress changes the names of the replacement images to slide11.png, slide22.png, etc

Can I set a filter in theme options that tells WP to overwrite existing images without changing the filenames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something i cooked up which was taken mainly from the plugin [**`Overwrite Uploads`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/overwrite-uploads/) but without the extra stuff

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_overrides','noneUniqueFilename');
function noneUniqueFilename($overrides){
    $overrides['test_form'] = false;
    $overrides['unique_filename_callback'] = 'nonUniqueFilenameCallback';
    return $overrides;
}

function nonUniqueFilenameCallback($directory, $name, $extension){
    $filename = $name . strtolower($extension);
    //remove old attachment
    removeOldAttach($filename);

    return $filename;
}

function removeOldAttach($filename){
    $arguments = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'meta_key'      => '_wp_attached_file',
        'meta_value'    => $filename,
        'post_type'     => 'attachment'
    );
    $Attachments_to_remove = get_posts($arguments);

    foreach($Attachments_to_remove as $a)
        wp_delete_attachment($a->ID, true);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working for me. Images with the same filename, still get uploaded as separate images as before. Does it work for you?

Comment: there's a footnote on the original script's download page that might be relevant or no? "NOTE: You have to make a small change to one of WordPress' core files for this to work. See the FAQ for details."

Comment: Bainternet: have you tested it? I'd love to get it to work, but so far, no go.

Comment: Yeah my bad i just remembered that i hacked the core file to get this to work.

Comment: So, no way to do it without hacking the core files? I need to include this in a shipping theme. Any thoughts?

Comment: The only way user around it is to handle the uploads yourself and avoid using WordPress for the needed functionality.

Comment: Version 1.1 of the plugin works without the Core hack.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make this work using a bit of @Bainternet's Answer without hacking the core.

This other Q&A was helpful as well: [query_posts: how to show all 'meta_value' containing a specific word?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/18799/12615)

The function [**`wp_unique_filename`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1626) has the filter `sanitize_file_name` just at the beginning, so we can hook there and do the checking and removal of the duplicate attachment.

I did basic localhost testings, please test it thoroughly before applying to a live site.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'filename_filter_wpse_28439', 10, 1 );

function filename_filter_wpse_28439( $name ) 
{
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'attachment',
        'meta_query' => array(
                array( 
                    'key' => '_wp_attached_file',
                    'value' => $name,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
    );
    $attachments_to_remove = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $attachments_to_remove as $attach )
        wp_delete_attachment( $attach->ID, true );

    return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter attachments based on file types, you could modify the meta_query in the code to include an additional condition based on the file extension. The file extension is typically part of the filename, and you can use it to filter attachments. However, keep in mind that relying solely on the file extension for security checks may not be foolproof, as filenames can be manipulated.

Here's an example modification to the code to filter attachments based on a specific file extension (e.g., .jpg):

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'filename_filter_wpse_28439', 10, 1 );

function filename_filter_wpse_28439( $name ) {
// Specify the file extension you want to target
  $target_extension = 'jpg';

  $args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key'     => '_wp_attached_file',
            'value'   => $name,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_attachment_ext',
            'value'   => $target_extension,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
  );

  $attachments_to_remove = get_posts( $args );

  foreach( $attachments_to_remove as $attach )
    wp_delete_attachment( $attach->ID, true );

  return $name;
}
```