# WP 3.3 > Still no option to enable automatic image overwrites?

Tags: uploads

I was really excited to see the new functionality with the media manager in WP 3.3 (specifically drag and drop uploads and automatic file type recognition)

But I was disheartened to see no relief in terms of the confusing manner in which WP continues to handle image overwrites (by appending a number to the image and creating a duplicate version).

Does anyone have a workaround that I can implement in my theme's functions.php to enable automatic image overwrites, replacing the original image with the new one, and without changing the filename?

Comment: How do you define duplicate image?

Comment: An image that resides on your server in the same directory and with the same filename as the one you are trying to upload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Media manager to overwrite files of same name?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28439/how-to-force-media-manager-to-overwrite-files-of-same-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another plugin out there worth checking out:

> [**Enable Media Replace**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enable-media-replace/)
>   *This plugin allows you to replace a file in your media library by uploading a new file in its place. No more deleting, renaming and re-uploading files!*

Answer (score 2):

Some searching revealed a plugin that seems to work, [Overwrite Uploads](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/overwrite-uploads/).  However, this requires a small change to the wp core, which isn't great.  So far I haven't found any way around this.

On a sidenote, I've used [WPlupload](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/) to replace the built in uploader.  I like how it lets me set a max upload file size and resolution.  not sure if it helps with your problem but might be useful to check out.

By the way, this has been [asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28439/how-to-force-media-manager-to-overwrite-files-of-same-name) a [few times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336724/wordpress-media-manager-force-image-overwrite) before with the same suggestion.